# Accessing a csv file into R from a website

Tags: r

I am trying to import into R the full indicator data .csv  which can be downloaded from the website:

https://data.oecd.org/money/broad-money-m3.htm

I tried:

```
m3 <- read.csv("https://data.oecd.org/money/broad-money-m3.htm")
head(m3)
tail(m3)
```

but this did not work.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's not CSV, that's a web page. If you want to *scrape* the data, one good package is `rvest`. I don't know of any StackExchange sites that are intended to be used as complete *tutorials* or *lesson plans*, and SO is no exception. While many answers do have sufficient detail to be useful as a mini-howto or such, I believe that that is the exception. And asking for that much is off-topic, please see [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the link *on* the page, so you can do:

```r
url <- paste0("https://stats.oecd.org/sdmx-json/data/DP_LIVE/",
              ".M3.TOT.IDX2015.M/OECD?contentType=csv&detail=code",
              "&separator=comma&csv-lang=en&startPeriod=2012")

df <- read.csv(url)

head(df)
#>   ï..LOCATION INDICATOR SUBJECT MEASURE FREQUENCY    TIME    Value Flag.Codes
#> 1         AUS        M3     TOT IDX2015         M 2012-01 79.09917         NA
#> 2         AUS        M3     TOT IDX2015         M 2012-02 79.59226         NA
#> 3         AUS        M3     TOT IDX2015         M 2012-03 80.08256         NA
#> 4         AUS        M3     TOT IDX2015         M 2012-04 80.48319         NA
#> 5         AUS        M3     TOT IDX2015         M 2012-05 81.13038         NA
#> 6         AUS        M3     TOT IDX2015         M 2012-06 81.88402         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>